# How to pass the input element as a parameter in ng-blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my input:

```
<input type="number" value="{{ bom.Id._Value }}" name="id" data-ng-model="bom.Id._Value" data-ng-blur="myClass.myFunc();" required>
```

If I pass `this` or `angular.element(this)` in the ng-blur I don't get the input element in the function. What I want is to receive the current input element in myFunc() as a parameter. What is the standard way for it?

Comment: Use `data-ng-blur="myClass.myFunc($event);"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<input type="number" value="{{ bom.Id._Value }}" name="id" data-ng-model="bom.Id._Value" data-ng-blur="myClass.myFunc($event);" required>
```

In Controller:

```
myClass.myFunc = function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
};
```